# 既存のjqueryに値を追加する

Tags: jquery

```
j$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var speed = 800;
    var href= $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(href == "#" || href == "" ? 'html' : href);
    var position = target.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:position}, speed, "swing");
    return false;
  });
});
```

こちら、スクロールトップに使用するコードなのですが、var position に値を付けたく思います。
例えばですが、現在のコードで表示されるposition位置より-50px上or下にスクロール位置を持ってきたい時、どのようにコードを変更したらいいでしょうか。

初歩的な質問＆分かりにくかったらすみません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

positionに+50すればいいだけかと思います。

```
var position = target.offset().top + 50;
```